# ES node failure with java.lang.AssertionError: java.text.ParseException

Tags: elasticsearch

ES service crashed. Found following stack trace :

`Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: java.text.ParseException: Failed to parse major version from "ield" (got: ield." "Fri, 20 Dec 2019 10:58:02 G  25753 MT".internal:index/shard/recovery/prepare_translog^@^@^@^@^@^@^@̏^Wrts_requ)  25754         at org.elasticsearch.index.store.StoreFileMetaData.<init>(StoreFileMetaData.java:68) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]  25755         at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$MetadataSnapshot.<init>(Store.java:806) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]  25756         at org.elasticsearch.indices.recovery.StartRecoveryRequest.readFrom(StartRecoveryRequest.java:122) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]  25757         at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.Streamable.lambda$newWriteableReader$0(Streamable.java:51) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]  25758         at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.newRequest(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:56) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]  25759         at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.handleRequest(TcpTransport.java:1508) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]  25760         at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.messageReceived(TcpTransport.java:1382) [elasticsearch-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]  25761         at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4MessageChannelHandler.channelRead(Netty4MessageChannelHandler.java:64) ~[?:?]  25762         at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[?:?]  25763         ... 24 more`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, one thing to add is that I was running this ES setup on top of openstack. Now, for some reason one of the boxes had a different set of TCP settings which possibly might have been causing this.

The reason I say this is because when I tried curl IP:9200 of that box multiple times quickly, sometimes the output got stuck just before version like mentioned below. Even the terminal through which I curled got stuck.

I think the same thing happened to other elasticsearch when they interacted with this ES and subsequently crashed.

```
{
  "name" : "###",
  "cluster_name" : "###",
  "cluster_uuid" : "####",
  "version" : {
```

Ultimately, I just asked for a new openstack VM with same base image as the other box to match the TCP settings and we haven't got that error in months now.

Things to note : 
1. We upgraded ES but that didn't help.
2. I cannot guarantee that TCP settings were the issue, but that is what I was targeting. It can be the OS image issue, underlying host issue etc. (Unfortunately, I lost the TCP settings)